# Iterate over elements in web.config

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, configuration, iis-7

Short question this time for a change...

Is there a way to iterate through the "location" elements in a web.config?

```
<configuration>
    ...
    <location path="some/path">
        <system.web>
            <authorization users="*" />
        </system.web>    
    </location>
    <location path="some/other/path">
        <system.web>
            <authorization users="?" />
        </system.web>    
    </location>
    ...
<configuration>
```

... and say have an output of something like:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>some/path</td>
        <td>authorization: *</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>some/other/path</td>
        <td>authorization: ?</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Cheers :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By [using the ConfigurationLocation class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.configurationlocation.aspx).

You can retrieve your web.config like this:

```
Configuration config = WebConfigurationManager.OpenWebConfiguration("~/web.config");
```

From there you can iterate through your locations:

```
foreach (ConfigurationLocation location in config.Locations)
{

}
```

Comment: I think this is definitely the way to do it, I actually attempted to implement a solution based on this.  The problem is I get a "exePath must be specified when not running inside a stand alone exe." error when I attempt open the configuration.

Comment: I'll update my answer and add a code example on how to open the web.config, but you might also need to implement an IConfigurationSectionHandler.

Comment: amazing, I just found that out on another post :)  Thanks for the answer!